# grunt-rebase – copy to multiple folders along with flattening the structure

Tags: gruntjs

I was wondering if anyone could help me with this.

I have a project where I am creating multiple html pages for different sites. Each of these sites shares a common assets folder (fonts, css, js etc) my directory layout is as follows:

```html
  |-- project
  |  |--assets
  |  |  |—-css
  |  |  |—-images
  |  |  |—-fonts
  |  |  |—-js
  |  |--site-1
  |  |  |—-index.html
  |  |--site-2
  |  |  |—-index.html
  |  |--site-3
  |  |  |—-index.html
```

What I would like to achieve is the following:

• A 'dist' folder that contains:

```html
  |-- dist
  |  |--site-1
  |  |  |—-index.html
  |  |  |—-style.min.css
  |  |  |—-image1.jpg
  |  |  |—-image2.jpg
  |  |  |—-image3.jpg etc...
  |  |  |—-scripts.min.js
  |  |  |—-font1.otf
  |  |  |—-font2.otf etc...
  |  |--site-2
  |  |  |—-index.html
  |  |  |—-style.min.css
  |  |  |—-image1.jpg
  |  |  |—-image2.jpg
  |  |  |—-image3.jpg etc...
  |  |  |—-scripts.min.js
  |  |  |—-font1.otf
  |  |  |—-font2.otf etc...
  |  |--site-3
  |  |  |—-index.html
  |  |  |—-style.min.css
  |  |  |—-image1.jpg
  |  |  |—-image2.jpg
  |  |  |—-image3.jpg etc...
  |  |  |—-scripts.min.js
  |  |  |—-font1.otf
  |  |  |—-font2.otf etc...
```

Just to explain the desired result:

• each site is 'flattened' within a directory, so that all of the assets, images, js, css, fonts are on the same level as the index.html file. (a requirement of the 3rd party that needs these)

• The corresponding links in each of the .html, .css & .js are updated the reflect the above.

• At times there might be more or less than just 3 'site' folders - so it would be great if I could 'loop' through and detect a folder name convention (??) - just a nice have if anyone smarter than me knows how to do this with a grunt task.

I have been trying the [grunt-rebase](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-rebase) task to make this work. It sounds like it is what I need, however I am really struggling with the documentation to make it work, along with a lack of experience with grunt tasks.

Any help would be great. If you need any more info please let me know.

EDIT - here is my grunt.js file - I have removed unneeded tasks and other bumpf for clarity.

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),


    copy: {
        main: {
            files: [
                {expand: true, cwd: 'project/', src: ['**/*'], dest: 'dist/', filter: 'isFile'}
            ]
        }
    },

    rebase: {
        scoped: {

            files: [{
                //css ref's
                expand: true,
                cwd: 'dist/assets/css/',
                src: '*.css',
                dest: 'dist/site-1/',
                reference: '../assets/images/',
                scopes: {
                    url: {
                        '../images/': '',
                        '../fonts/': ''
                    }
                }
            }, {
                //html ref's
                expand: true,
                cwd: 'dist/site-1/',
                src: '**/*.html',
                dest: 'dist/site-1/',
                reference: true,
                scopes: {
                    url: {
                        '../assets/images/': ''
                    },
                    img: {
                        '../assets/images/': ''
                    },
                    link: {
                        '../assets/css/': ''
                    },
                    script: {
                        '../assets/js/': ''
                    }
                }
            }, {
                //images
                expand: true,
                cwd: 'dist/assets/images/',
                src: '**/*',
                dest: 'dist/site-1/'
            }, {
                //fonts
                expand: true,
                cwd: 'dist/assets/fonts/',
                src: '**/*',
                dest: 'dist/site-1/'
            },
            {
                //js
                expand: true,
                cwd: 'dist/assets/js/',
                src: '*.js',
                dest: 'dist/site-1/'
            }]
        }
    }

});

//1 - make copy of entire prod directory to 'dist folder'
//2 - rebase task
//3 - TODO - delete dist/assets folder (not needed after rebase)

grunt.registerTask('Create Exported Project', [
    'copy',
    'rebase'
]);
```

};

The above rebase task works....but only for one folder that i hard code into the 'dest' field for each scope (the 'site-1' folder).

I was hoping for some flexibility to be able to loop through all folders that match a condition (maybe the string - 'site-').

Comment: Can you post your gruntfile?

Comment: Hi thanks for taking a look. I just added my gruntfile without my other tasks for clarity here.